# How to print white illustration in black box on white paper?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, print-design, affinity-designer

I'm trying to print a white flower design inside a black box which will be printed on white photo paper on an Epson SC P5000 printer.

I would like the white designs inside the box to appear as negative space. What is the best way to achieve this? Have the white illustration be #FFFFFF or knock it out somehow?

Also I will be exporting this image into Photoshop from Affinity Designer as a smart vector object.

Answer (score 4):

Simply set the white to white and print. There's no need to knock out anything, the white essentially creates the knockout. The black will print leaving the white areas blank.

White, for printing, pretty much always means "paper". The only time white may actually mean "print white" is for specific printing processes such as flexography or silkscreen.

Comment: Thanks just the answer I was looking for.